# Why am I seeing a large spike in Data ingestion from performance counter data?

Tags: azure-application-insights, cost-management

From looking at my Cost Management reports for Application Insights, I've noticed a large spike in data ingestion related to Performance Counters.

[image: Cost Management Reporting]

[Link to larger image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vgbCqUDNPq7yy0qDFAIuJPi8_O7eZO-x)

However, I'm not seeing any significant correlation in the number of requests spiking for the same period.

[image: Request Metrics Report]

[Link to larger image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kA9yyemgsobu95QBs0JH0cIU3FOOMxCG)

What can I do to understand the root cause of this issue?

**Additional Information**

After some debugging, I was able to get to the bottom of this.

The usage spiked on Sep 7 and Sep 8 and then tapered off on the 9th and 10th.

The change that I made on the 6th Sept was to upgrade Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore from version 2.6.1 to version 2.7.1. Version 2.7.1 has ILogger integration baked in.

So, what I believe happened is that, after deploying the upgraded version of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore, I may have had the Logging verbosity turned up too high for the performance counter telemetry data and subsequently changed it a couple of days later when I noticed it.

I hope this helps someone else who may run into this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a cleaner way to achieve the disabling of the PerformanceCounterModule (and other modules which cause excessive/unneeded logging);

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
{
    options.EnablePerformanceCounterCollectionModule = false;
    options.InstrumentationKey = configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Application Insights 2.7.1 has enabled ILogger captured by default, but it only captures Warning or above log messages. So unless you application is generating a lot of Warning or above level Ilogger logs, this should not result in a big spike in usage.
This behavior can be changed to filter logs further if too much logs are reported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#control-logging-level
From the 1st screenshot you shared, it looks like performance counter is the only type which spiked - ilogger integration cannot explain this spike, as it only reports logs.

More logical explanation is the PerformanceCounter module itself which was NOT supported in versions earlier than 2.7.1. You can remove performance counter collection with the following snipped in ConfigureServices() method in startup.cs

using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector;

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

    // The following removes PerformanceCollectorModule to disable perf-counter collection.
    var performanceCounterService = services.FirstOrDefault<ServiceDescriptor>(t => t.ImplementationType == typeof(PerformanceCollectorModule));
    if (performanceCounterService != null)
    {
     services.Remove(performanceCounterService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @cijothomas, what you've said makes sense.

Surely everyone who upgrades to 2.7.1 will face this issue?  Is there a configuration setting that can be used to control the performance counter module?

Comment: My response above shows how to remove performancecountermodule.

Comment: I do not know how you are seeing a huge spike in data volume from perf counter unless you have quite a large number of servers. Because performance counters sents counters once every minute only, and this is typically very small overall volume. But perfcounters are emitted from every instance, so if the number of instances are high, it can all emit counters every min.

Comment: Thanks for the help @cijothomas.  In my case, the performance counter data is coming from a single, low-volume Azure AppService.  Seems odd.  I might mention it on GitHub as an issue.